# Laravel 4.2 ends session when spamming ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, session

I have a chat system that posts user's messages via ajax to a controller that deals with the data.

For testing purposes if I hold down return (continuously firing off post requests) I eventually hit a `401 Unauthorized`. After reloading the page I can see that I've been logged out - thus leading me to realise this action has, for some reason, cleared the session.

Now obviously in production I wouldn't allow the user to fire off requests so rapidly - but nevertheless, I need to understand why this is happening.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a similar issue to https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5416#issuecomment-68395469

> Because session reads DO NOT respect file write locks, a request calling Session::start that HAPPENS to read the session file at the exact moment that the write call in the other request is between ftruncate and fwrite will receive NO DATA, thereby assuming that NO session exists and creating a new one, hence the new token. Because this has to occur at that exact moment, it does not always occur, and is more likely to occur when many short requests happen concurrently.

You might try a different session driver than the default `file` one.

Comment: @Capio Yeah. Still, I tend to prefer redis, elasticache, or APC as drivers. They tend to be better than the file driver.

Comment: Switched to Redis, pleased.